# How to mouse hover a parent element and subsequently click on child element using Selenium and Action class

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, mousehover, webdriverwait

I wrote a test to hover mouse on an Element which has a link underneath it and to click the subElement. I keep getting NullPointerException. It had work previously and stopped working again.

```
Actions mouseHover = new Actions(driver);
mouseHover.moveToElement(ParentElement);
mouseHover.moveToElement(subElement);
mouseHover.click(subElement);
```

Comment: Share the exception stack trace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code attempts you havn't invoked the `perform()` method for [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261894/7429447). You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the elements and can use the following solution:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
//other lines of code
Actions mouseHover = new Actions(driver);
mouseHover.moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ParentElement)))).perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(subElement))).click();
```

---

### Update

As you are still seeing the error as:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:882) at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:68)
```

This implies that *WebDriver*  instance i.e. the *driver* is not accessible from this part of the code. The issue may be related to *driver* being **null** as you did not extend the `Base` class in the **Test** class. Ensure that the *driver* is accessible.

### Related Discussions:

- [What is this Error: at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936414/what-is-this-error-at-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checknotnull)
- [Why does the NullPointerException occur on the Selenium driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520042/why-does-the-nullpointerexception-occur-on-the-selenium-driver)

Comment: I have tried both options and didn't work. Here is the stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:882)
 at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:68)
 at HoverShemes.Order_CreateANewOrder.setHoverSearch(Order_CreateANewOrder.java:40)
 at testClasses.HomeTests.Hovers_Test.getHoverSearch(Hovers_Test.java:14)

Comment: @user9790882 Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: i have extended the Base class in the Test class and still got the same error. Thanks

Comment: This works now. I found that I had WebDriver driver;  in my test class and have removed this. Thank you

Comment: @user9790882 Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It may be trying to click the element before it appears. Try to use a web driver wait before you move to the subelement. ( Since it worked previously I guess this should be the issue )

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.LOCATOR("subelement")));
```

It'll look like,

```
Actions mouseHover = new Actions(driver);
mouseHover.moveToElement(ParentElement);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.LOCATOR("subelement")));

mouseHover.moveToElement(subElement);
mouseHover.click(subElement);
```

Cheerz

Comment: Muditha Perera, i have tried your option and still geting the same error.